# Flutter Yandex Mobile ADs

Tags: flutter, yandex

I use Yandex mobile advertising in Flutter. While the application is being compiled, I create and upload a banner ad. I have 7 screens in the application and I show this banner ad on all my screens. However, when switching between screens, ads disappear and it takes a long time to load again. Do I need to create a banner with a separate ID for each screen, or do I need to create more than one banner widget within the application with the same ID? How can I solve this problem?

I tried to reload the ad in InitState on each screen, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.